# How to respond to a ContextMenuStrip item click

Tags: c#, windows, events, contextmenu

Currently I have the following code:

```
ContextMenuStrip contexMenuuu = new ContextMenuStrip();

contexMenuuu.Items.Add("Edit ");
contexMenuuu.Items.Add("Delete " );
contexMenuuu.Show();
```

How can I add an event to be processed when an item gets clicked?

Answer (score 43):

This can be done using the following code:

```
ContextMenuStrip contexMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();

contexMenu.Items.Add("Edit ");
contexMenu.Items.Add("Delete ");
contexMenu.Show();
contexMenu.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(
    contexMenu_ItemClicked);

// ...

void contexMenu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e) {
    ToolStripItem item = e.ClickedItem;
    // your code here
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
// ...

ToolStripItem item = contexMenu.Items.Add("Edit ");
item.Click += new EventHandler(item_Click);

// ...

void item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ToolStripItem clickedItem = sender as ToolStripItem;
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Seems that while `ItemClicked` allows you to retrieve the clicked-on item through the `sender`, sadly the `item.Click` event handler supports no such thing... and `ItemClicked` only works for first-level menu items, not for sub-menus.

Comment: I'd be interested to know how you get the clicked-on item from the sender, as when I tried it the sender seems to be the ContextMenuStrip for both the Click and ItemClicked events.

Comment: Oh, found it : ((ContextMenuStrip)sender).SourceControl. I would have expected that to work for the Click event too, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 7):

[Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160940.aspx) method returns [ToolStripItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.aspx). So you can add handle to Click event

```
        var item = contexMenuuu.Items.Add("Edit ");
        item.Click += methodToBeInvoked;
```