# Programming Context Menu

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

I have a `ContextMenuStrip` That I create in code:

```
ContextMenuStrip menu;
public Loader()
{
    menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
    menu.Items.Add("Set Complete");
    menu.Items.Add("Set Review");
    menu.Items.Add("Set Missing");
}
```

I need to add code that will run when a certain Item is clicked. So far I have tried this:

```
if (menu.Items[0].Selected)
{
    //code
}

if (menu.Items[1].Selected)
{
    //code
}

if (menu.Items[2].Selected)
{
   //code
}
```

But (suprise, suprise) It doesnt work.

I think I might need to set up an event handler for each Item, but am unsure how to do this as I created the `ContextMenuStrip` with code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a contextMenuStrip item click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789023/how-to-make-a-contextmenustrip-item-click-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subscribe the click events. I have changed your sample so it should work:

```
public Loader()
{
    var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
    var menuItem = menu.Items.Add("Set Complete");
    menuItem.Click += OnMenuItemSetCompleteClick;
    menuItem = menu.Items.Add("Set Review");
    menuItem.Click += OnMenuItemSetReviewClick;
    menuItem = menu.Items.Add("Set Missing");
    menuItem.Click += OnMenuItemSetMissingClick;
}

private void OnMenuItemSetCompleteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}

private void OnMenuItemSetReviewClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}

private void OnMenuItemSetMissingClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add event handlers to the individual menu items (`Click` event), or to the ContextMenuStrip itself (`ItemClicked` event).

Take a look here: [How to respond to a ContextMenuStrip item click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789023/how-to-make-a-contextmenustrip-item-click-event)

Comment: +1. I personally love to use the `ItemClicked` event, especially when each item's code is quite short (~5 lines). That way, I handle several items in one subroutine.

Comment: Yes, the `ItemClicked` is really helpful, especially when menu items share some common UI logic.