# Right click menu customise on gridControl / gridView1 (C# / DevExpress) Programatically

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

how to customize the right click menu on gridcontrol? I try tp put the export option on the menu. I try to search inside the Grid Design still unable to find it. Try to google this for weeks. Need guidance from the master. TQ

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a single control name **contextmenu** you can add it from code or designer then add some events. you can google it youself or [Adding a right click menu to an item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823883/adding-a-right-click-menu-to-an-item)

Comment: I know is something to do with DataGridView header menu, i google many samples, still unable to understand, as i try search for the example code (in programmatically way) for guidance. I know need manually code in the option into the existing gridview right click menu. But i still miss out some important key step to do so. 

 I try to add the menu option into the existing one.

Comment: Hi CodeFarmer, I solved my case, due to i manage found our code of  DLL. Anyway your guidance still very useful for my next full complete front end system development. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the GridView's [PopupMenuShowing event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_PopupMenuShowingtopic.aspx) and customize the built-in Grid menu(s):

```
private void gridView1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.MenuType != DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMenuType.Column)
        return;

    DXMenuItem restoreItem = new DXMenuItem() { Caption = "Restore Layout" };
    restoreItem.Click += restoreItem_Click;

    e.Menu.Items.Add(restoreItem);
}

private void restoreItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Restoring layout...");
}
```

See also: [How to: Implement Custom Menu in XtraGrid Control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument10326)