# How to Implements Control Tasks

Tags: c#, user-controls, task

Hello im creating a custom user control.
I no have problem whit paint, events and more, but i have a simple question.
How to implements Control Tasks?

https://i.ibb.co/JRQ69NB/Immagine.png

How to add more feature on this task?
Google dont help me about this feature.
Unknow for me.

Comment: Do you mean how do you implement a Context Menu? Or do you want help with docking specifically?

Comment: I want implement more feature in Tasks Menu show on Edit mode.
For example, if i add listview,Tasks menu have Edit Item. I want to implement a tasks like this.

Comment: Popup menus like this are normally called 'Context Menus' and the items on it are 'MenuItems'. This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823883/adding-a-right-click-menu-to-an-item    I'm not sure what the SimbaToolBar is. Is it something you wrote, or a third-party tool?

Comment: @RobinBennet is a my Control. I ask this question because if i write on header class [Docking(DockingBehavior.Ask)] if you find reference, source code show hot Docking Menu appear in DisegnTime. On source code, i see only a public sealed class and simple enum "Ask" or "Never". For this, i think exist a method for show more operation on this Tasks Menu in DesignTime.